# VCL40.bpl missing when installing package in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, installation, package

I want to install an old package in Delphi XE3.

I have made the modifications needed and construction of package is OK, but when i ask to install it, i have the error : VCL40.pbl missing.

How to resolve this and get rid of this error ?

Thanks !

Comment: What version was this package designed for?

Comment: @BlueMan This is the least of your concerns. Porting from ANSI D4 to Unicode XE3 is a big task.

Answer (score 4):

Open your package `.dpk` file. You will find `vcl40` under `requires` clause

```
requires
  vcl40;
```

Rename `vcl40` to `vcl` to fix this error.

Delphi packages are Delphi version specific. Every Delphi version creates different compiled package (`.bpl`) from same code and compiled packages cannot be shared among different Delphi versions.

All Delphi `RTL/VCL/FMX` packages have suffix that marks Delphi version they are intended for and avoids conflicts when you have multiple packages for different versions installed on your system. In Delphi 4 when your package used some other package that version number was included in your `requires` clause. That is why you have `vcl40`. In later versions (Delphi 7 or 6) that was changed introducing package suffix that removed need to write version number in requires clause still allowing compiled packages to have different numbers for different Delphi versions.

That is why you have `vcl` instead of `vcl170` in Delphi XE3.

Recommended practice is that you also follow suffix version numbering for your own packages to avoid conflicts. To do so go to `Package Options` -> `Description` and set LIB suffix to desired version. It can be set to anything you want but it is also good practice to use same numbering scheme as Delphi packages and for XE3 that would be `170`.

When you compile your package with suffix set generated `.bpl` will be named `MyPackageName170.bpl`

Comment: I have done already this.
But when i complie the package, there is no erro, but there is no genration of the .BPL: this is the old .bpl

Comment: I added additional explanation about package numbering schemes. When you build and install your package your new .bpl file will be created. You probably just cannot find it. If you haven't changed folders during installation default folder is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Bpl`

Answer (score 0):

Search for all copies of the BPL you're trying to install, both runtime and design and delete them. I had a similar problem when trying to install a package on XE6, kept wanting rtl170.bpl (its an XE3 bpl). Turns out there was an old version of the runtime BPL in c:\Windows\SysWOw65. Once I delete that copy installation was ok.